# Showing details for a custom entity

Tags: entity, crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have seen that whenever for any case I enter a customer's name, the corresponding details of the customer pop up on the right side. I want the same to happen for one of my custom entity "Store". How can I achieve that?

Have attached screenshot for reference, context is CRM Dynamics 365.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place Quick View account's form inside your custom Store entity main form.

Quick View sample training video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn9gPtPUPX0

Comment: Okay @Piotr go it. Thaks!

Comment: What you mean to say ? In the first stage customer selects "find customer", to which customer details are displayed. Then "find store" and I want store details to be displayed.